# Rust: no method named `join` found for struct `std::string::String`

Tags: collections, rust, compiler-errors

Hmm why is this not working?

```
let numcities = 40;
let mut file = std::fs::File::create(args[3].clone()).unwrap();

file.write((0..numcities).map(|i| i.to_string()).collect::<String>().join("->")).unwrap();
```

Compilation error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `join` found for struct `std::string::String` in the current scope
  --> main.rs:42:72
   |
42 |         file.write((0..numcities).map(|i| i.to_string()).collect::<String>().join("->")).unwrap();
   |                                                                              ^^^^ method not found in `std::string::String`
```

Comment: You need `.collect::<Vec<String>>()`. Once you've already collected your numbers to a big string, it's too late to join them, they've already been joined.

Comment: because these is no join method on string. BTW your code don't match with error message.

Comment: Doesnt write return the number of bytes written? it will be a single number, not sure anything is gonna get joint there anyway....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to collect into an intermediary `Vec<String>`:

```rust
let data = ["A", "B", "C"];
let result = data.iter().map(|s| s.to_string()).collect::<Vec<String>>().join("->"));
```

In **nightly 1.53**, you can use [`intersperse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.intersperse) for example:

```rust
#![feature(iter_intersperse)]

fn main() {
    let data = vec!["A", "B", "C"];
    let result = data
        .iter()
        .map(|x| x.to_string())
        .intersperse("->".to_string())
        .collect::<String>();
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab41750b490ddb6355017d77f4302e2e)

Comment: Alternatively [there's  a `join` in itertools which works with iterators](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.join) (as well as a free functions for iterables).

Comment: And if you're on nightly with `iter_intersperse` why not just use `intersperse("->".to_string())`? `String`'s clone and while it will trigger one more allocation (for the separator value) that seems unlikely to be a big issue compared to the complexity of this `interpserse_with`. Alternatively, you could just define `let separator = "->"` and then have the `intersperse_with` callback be `|| separator.to_string()`, the iterator seems wholly unnecessary no?

Comment: Also of note: itertools' join [may be slower than collecting to a vector then joining](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/6q4uqc/help_whats_the_best_way_to_join_an_iterator_of/dkv5g06).